# How to set data to other Component in Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I want to set data from a component to another component with vuejs. Here's my code:
http://quangtri.herokuapp.com/s/ByNN4FE-b
Where am I wrong? Please help me! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a `function` in your `bus.$on`, so `this` is not what you think it is. Use an arrow function instead and it works.

```js
const bus = new Vue();

Vue.component('coupon', {
  data() {
    return {
      name: 'tri'
    }
  },
  template: `
 <div>
 <p>{{ name }}</p>
 <button type="button" @click="batdau">Go</button>
 </div>
 `,
  methods: {

    batdau(name) {
      this.name = 'Maria';
    }
  },
  created() {

  },
  mounted() {
    bus.$on('applied', (name) => {
      alert(name);
      this.name = 'Romeo';
    })
  }
});

Vue.component('couponmore', {

  template: `
 <button type="button" @click="nosukien">Let Set Name</button>
 `,
  methods: {

    nosukien() {
      bus.$emit('applied', 'John');
    }
  }

});

new Vue({
  el: '#root',
  data: {
    couponApplied: false
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.3/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">
<coupon></coupon>
<couponmore></couponmore>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because in that piece of code, `this` is *window*, not the component.

```
bus.$on('applied', function(name){
    alert(name);
    this.$data.name ='Romeo';
})
```

Also you are setting data using `this.$data.name` instead of simply `this.name`, I'm not sure about it, but this could result in reactive data issues.

### Solution:

If you are using ES6, you can do this:

```
bus.$on('applied', (name) => {
    alert(name);
    this.name ='Romeo';
})
```

This is called **arrow function**, and when using an arrow function instead of a normal function, the value of `this` inside the function will be the same as in the parent scope (so, the component instance who contains `data`).

If you are using vanilla javascript, use `.bind(this)` at the end:

```
bus.$on('applied', function (name) {
    alert(name);
    this.name ='Romeo';
}.bind(this))
```

Comment: The function in your second example should be `bus.$on('applied', function(name){...}.bind(this))`