# How to update component's data property from another component in vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have two components A & B, both are not child or parent of each other.
A has data as

```
export default {
    data() {
        return { 
           info1: 'info1'
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to update this info1 proppoerty from component B.
Is it possible?

Comment: will you please share some of your code

Comment: See also this answer using an external event bus: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44185404/8487308

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's possible in more than one way. I would suggest using [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/intro.html) for this, as it makes things easier down the road when multiple components need to grab/update values.

Vuex is a library for state management and are thus build for what you are trying to achieve. It also makes it a lot easier to inspect values during development.

Answer (score 3):

You can use $root and $refs for this, attach ref to both components, like:

```
<component-a ref="compa"></component-a>
<component-b ref="compb"></component-b>
```

Now here is the important part, you need to follow the exact path to each component.Example you want to access component A in B, use

```
this.$root.$children[0].$refs.compa.info1
```

or it would be

```
this.$root.$children[0].$children[0].$refs.compa.info1
```

or

```
this.$root.$children[0].$children[1].$refs.compa.info1
```

According to your app and components relation to each other. In this way you can access and update the info1 from component A.This is one way to achieve it.